# Brower opens while downloading data android

Tags: android, http, browser, https, download

```
WebView webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(URL);
    webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
    {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength)
        {
            //for downloading directly through download manager
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }
    });
```

how can i download without opening the browser..
i searched over the net but coudnt find solution..

Or any trick  with which the user cannot see the web browser is welcomed
And i am newbie so try to explain
pls help me with it thanks in advance..
:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsyncTask to download data in background. AsyncTask runs in a separate thread and not in the Main thread which happens to be the best method for downloading and stuff like that

Comment: is there no way by the method i show in my question..btw thanks 4 answering

Comment: Using AsyncTask wouldn't open the browser, which is basicaly what you're trying to impliment right?